# Store HTTP/SOAP requests in case no connection is available

Tags: javascript

I am working on JavaScript project in which we call some SOAP APIs to receive data and then we display this in front end. The server which hosts the back end can go down sometimes, resulting in the failure of the API calls. I want to queue all API calls in front end which fails when server was down and keep polling server till it comes back online and after that start dequeuing API requests from queue to handle them from front end. Could somebody please help me by explaining this can be implemented in JavaScript?

I am using simple javascript http request to invoke the APIs. Currently, what we do is if API fails, we keep on calling it again and again for some time till it gives response. The problem in this approach is if there are multiple different API failures, only last one in tracked. I want to keep track of all failed API calls and call them in sequence once server is back online. It would be nice if it can be done without using external library.

Current code:

API call:

```
function sendXmlRequest(payload) {
// Build http request
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('POST', endpoint, true);
http.timeout = 30000;
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/xml');

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (http.readyState === 4 && http.responseXML) {
    if (http.status === 200) {
      setResponsePayload(http.responseXML.documentElement);
    } else if (http.status === 500) {
      setErrorResponsePayload(http.responseXML.documentElement);
    }
  }
};

http.onerror = function() {
  setErrorResponse();

}
http.ontimeout = function() {
  setErrorResponse();
}

// Send request
http.send(payload);
}
```

Retrying:

```
function retryConnection() {
 setTimeout(function() {
   sendXmlRequest(payload);
 }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: hi and welcome to stackoverflow, i order to prupose you the best approch. could you provide us example of what you have try so far ? What is your actual stack ? Is ok for you to add extra library ? Thanks by advance.

Comment: I am using simple javascript http request to invoke the APIs. Currently, what we do is if API fails, we keep on calling it again and again for some time till it gives response. The problem in this approach is if there are multiple different API failures, only last one in tracked. I want to keep track of all failed API calls and call them in sequence once server is back online. It would be nice if it can be done without using external library.

Comment: Please share with us your actual implementation.

Comment: @Yanis-git updated

Answer (score 1):

you may can do something like following :

```
var fetch = {
  queue: [],
  request : function (url, method) {
    // Create the XHR request
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var self = this;
    // Return it as a Promise
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      // Setup our listener to process compeleted requests
      request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        // Only run if the request is complete
        if (request.readyState !== 4) return;
        // Process the response
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {
          // If successful
          resolve(request);
        } else {
          self.queue.push({url, method});
          // If failed
          reject({
            status: request.status,
            statusText: request.statusText
          });
        }
      };
      // Setup our HTTP request
      request.open(method || 'GET', url, true);
      // Send the request
      request.send();
    });
  },
  retry: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.queue.forEach(function(meta) {
        console.log(meta);
        self.request(meta.url, meta.method).then(
          () => self.queue.filter(e => e.url !== meta.url && e.method !== meta.method)
        );
    });
  }
};


setInterval(() => {
  fetch.retry();
}, 10000);
// Success case.
fetch.request('https://api.github.com/emojis','GET')
  .then(console.log, console.error);
//Error case.
  fetch.request('https://api.github.com/eee','GET')
  .then(console.log, console.error);
```

First i have object `fetch` which have 3 parts :

```
var fetch = {
  queue: [], // on error, we add url and method on the queue.
  request : function (url, method) {
    // Perform request.
  },
  retry: function() {
    // Retry what ever you have on queue. Remove when success.
  }
};
```

Then, on request, when some error occur, i add all information needed to replay the request inside the queue array.

On other side, retry method will loop on this queue, and replay all requests failed.

---

To keep code simplest as possible i have introduce weakness on my code. If you want to manipulate Ajax request answer from backend, and if this request failed then go to queue and success after couple of trying. You are not actually able to retreive the api answer with it.

if this case is important for you, let me know i will prupose another (more complicated) approch.